# How to parse multiple json data into array of objects in Angular?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

Im trying to read multiple json object into an array in Angular, but can't figure out how to parse multiple json objects into an array of objects and map it to the Blog object data fields

**JSON Data**

```
{
"Blogs":[
    {"title":"Demo Blog 1", "summary":"Demo Blog 1 summary"},
    {"title":"Demo Blog 2", "summary":"Demo Blog 2 summary"},
    {"title":"Demo Blog 3", "summary":"Demo Blog 3 summary"}
]
}
```

**Component class**

```
constructor(private appService: AppConfigService, private blogs: Blog[]) { }

showBlogResource(){
    this.appService.getBlogResource().subscribe((data: Blog[]) => {
      // read all blog data from json & store it into array blogs
    });
  }
```

**Service Class**

```
getBlogResource() {
    return this.http.get<Blog[]>(this.apiEndpoint + apiResource.blogs).pipe(retry(3), catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

**Blog class**

```
export interface Blog {
  title: string;
  summary: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
blogs: Blog[];
constructor(private appService: AppConfigService) { }

showBlogResource(){
    this.appService.getBlogResource().subscribe((data: Blog[]) => {
        this.blogs = data;
    });
}
```

And maybe change getBlogResource to (added the map operator to get the "Blogs" property from the json)

```
return this.http.get<Blog[]>(this.apiEndpoint + apiResource.blogs).pipe(map(res => res.Blogs), retry(3), catchError(this.handleError))
```